# Header of SOAP message modified by JBOSS-REMOTING

Tags: java, soap, jboss, cxf, soap-client

I developped a client service using APACHE-CXF to consume an external webervice from our application. Everything went fine:
-Class generated from the wsdl
-The call works well from a simple main test or locally when testing it wth SOAPUI.

but when I deploy the sources of our server (JBOSS 5.1),the call fails. I printed the soap request:

```
POST /ws/TET_DOC
SOAPAction: "http://www.testDoc.be/testDoc/getDoc"
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
JBoss-Remoting-Version: 22
User-Agent: JBossRemoting - 2.5.1 (Flounder)
Host: post.netpost:55405
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

The problem comes from the attribute: ACCEPT. It has been modified by JBOSS-REMOTING. It should be:

```
Accept: text/xml, multipart/related, text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
```

So I have 2 questions:

1. Why jboss changed the attribute "accept" of the message?
2. How can I set the "accept" attribute ob jboss side? I tried this upfront (before calling the operation but it didn't work):

   ```
   final Map<String, List<String>> requestHeaders = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
   requestHeaders
       .put(
           "Accept",
           Arrays
               .asList("text/html, multipart/related, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2"));
   ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put(
       MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, requestHeaders);
   ```

thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WAW!! finally I could solve the problem: spend 3 days on it pfff!!!

We're using JBOSS 5.1 with JDK6 and I don't know why, natives classes from jboss are being picked up instead of the ones from JDK. 
And even if i added some new apache-cxf libraries to $JBOSS_HOME/common/lib--> I ended up with cast errors on client Proxy.

Solution:

I cleaned up everything and started from scratch with:

1. installing jbossws-cxf in my server (JBOSS 5.1)
2. put some libraries in $JBOSS_HOME/lib/endorsed: last versions of woodstox (Otherwise, you'll run into "Cannot create secure XMLInputFactory")

Now everything works fine :)